# Color (colour) differences between browsers?

Tags: css, colors

I have just noticed a site I am working on looks different in Chrome than other browsers (saf, ff), everything is more saturated in Chrome, even a background-color rgb.

I can't figure out what is making this happen, can't be anything to do with img color profiles otherwise the rgb background color surely wouldnt be affected.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

There are small differences for all of them. 
Take a look at this article : http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

There is also difference based on the monitor you use and your OS colors settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! The strange thing is its Chrome that is being the awkward one, FF & Saf are the same.. would have thought it was a webkit/moz thing

from what I can figure out Chrome still ignores color profiles - strange but good to know

also found this link which is pretty interesting and useful http://www.color.org/version4html.xalter

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html) also explains browser color differences because of the optional color management feature