# background-color displays incorrect color

Tags: html, css, background-color

I've started with a very basic HTML5 site and set background-color of the header div to `#3D7D99` but the browser displays it as `#35728E`. What's wrong?

**EDIT:** No the CSS property is not overwritten anywhere due to Safaris developer tools. (Try it yourself http://pigeonapp.github.io/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have other stylesheets? What browser are you using? Any Javascript/plugins? We definitely need more information than you've provided so far...

Comment: It's showing `#35728E` because it's `#35728E`. It's either being overridden or something else. Show us some relevant code.

Comment: Can't say it without code, live-website? or fiddle?!

Comment: Code please? We can't help without code

Comment: @DrydenLong As described tested it with BASIC html 5 without anything else. (No JS, no additional CSS then the background.)

Comment: @miho That wasn't described, but implied. "Basic" could mean any of several things so rather than assuming, we needed clarification. Now that we know you have no JS or other stylesheets, could you provide us with the code you do have?

Comment: Your post says that the browser is displaying the color as `#35728E` but your screenshot shows it as `#3D7D99`... I'm confused, how do you know it's `#35728E`?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/pigeonapp/pigeonapp.github.io

Comment: I checked it by picking the color with [Sip](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/sip/id507257563?mt=12). (I've wondered why the color in my Photoshop Mockup looked different then on HTML page.)

Comment: Ok, there's your problem. When I open your screenshot in Photoshop and use the color picker it comes out as `#3e7a95` Using the color picker is going to get you different results in different programs on different OSs and on different screens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "very basic homepage" means you've already discounted CSS rules and whatnot, it could also be related to the [monitor, os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988092/css-colors-are-different) or [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237600/color-colour-differences-between-browsers).

**Edit:**
Based on the examples, it's important to note that color picking from screenshots instead of picking from the hex rendered value in html will further complicate things due to browser rendering differences (specifically for images that don't have defined color profiles), [safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4146673) being [no exception](https://news.layervault.com/stories/9516-safari-displays-colors-incorrectly).

Comment: I've added a link the HTML source. And about the monitor, os: I'm aware of that, but I've picked it with a color picker app on the screen so there shouldn't be any deviation caused by the display.

Comment: And I just noticed: It works in Firefox. I've just only tested Safari and Coda integrated browser (which may be Safari too).

Comment: Fwiw, in Chrome on Win 7 picking from rendered HTML i get #3D7D99..

Answer (score 0):

The color is overriden by another css rule. Try `!important` and see if it works, if it does, then you must remove `!important` an find the section in your CSS when it is overriden. Use Google Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug extension(Firefox) and inspect the element.

Comment: Based on the OP's updated post with screenshot and referenced code, this is incorrect.

Comment: @admdrew , yes, but when I posted the answer there was nothing, no code no screenshot, just a question.