# How can I fix a color matching error between a PNG and GIF?

Tags: html, css

I have a website that has a single, large animated pixel art gif in the center of it.

On either side of the large gif is a div that expands horizontally. The background image of these divs is a tile-able PNG.

This is so the 'scene' can fill screen widths up to 5736px without distorting the center gif.

The problem: The PNG tile colors are different in the browser than they are in Photoshop, so they don't match with the centerpiece gif. Tested in Safari, Firefox, Chrome on macOS.

Saving and opening the tiles and gifs in Photoshop show that the colors are the same. But when viewing them in the browser (or taking a screenshot of the browser), it's apparent they're different.

Furthermore, neither color is the "correct" color (#080910).

[image: Color matching issue between PNG, left, and GIF, right.]

Neither the gif or the PNG has any transparency, or anything on top of them. I'm at a bit of a loss and would appreciate any help - I feel like I might be missing something about how browsers render images.

### HTML

```
<div id="hero">

    <div class="scene tile" id="lefTile"></div>

    <div class="scene" id="centerpiece"></div>

    <div class="scene tile" id="rightTile"></div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
#hero {
    width: 5736px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-size: 1736px auto;
}

.scene {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
}

#centerpiece {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1736px;

    background-image: url(img/hero.gif);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.tile {
    width: 2000px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;


#leftTile {
    background-image: url(img/left-tile.png);
    background-position: right bottom;
}

#rightTile {
    background-image: url(img/right-tile.png);
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to the thread here, it's already been asked
[Color (colour) differences between browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237600/color-colour-differences-between-browsers)

also the possible reasons can be
・color profiles (sRGB, AdobeRBG etc.)
・temperature differences of monitor (3000k~ etc k=kelvin)
・gif only supports 256 colors?

if you really want the accurate colors on your monitor you can use monitors for photographers, pro video editors that is color calibrated from EIZO, NEC etc. but they are expensive :)

but the downside is you can only see the differences in color unless other person has the same monitors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and summary - I'm not sure if this is quite the same issue though. The colors in the two background images (PNG and GIF) in question are the same in all browsers I can test, and on 3 different monitors. The images have the same color profiles. Let me know if you have any other hints!

Comment: @oldpal I need to see the actual site.